# silverlight Textbox not updated when underlying collection's corresponding property is changed

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, observablecollection, converters

As an example

I have a 2 text boxes. Text of both text boxes are bound to class Name {String fullname, String funnyName}; They are not directly bound but by a converter

They are implementing `INotifyChanged` and the bound `DataContext` is `ObservableCollection` and all other standard stuff.

This template is bound so that I have 2 text boxes in one row and the listbox has 10 rows
THe question is :

when I change fullname in text box 1, I go and change the funnyname in the bound collection.

This is not not reflected immediately onto the GUI.

How can I achieve this? I don't want to update entire list box, and I don't want to directly bind it to another property in my class, but through a converter. The converter is not called when property changes from say "TOm" to "dick" i.e converter is only called first time. Next whenever some property changes and

```
this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("FunnyName"));
```

is called, the converter is not invoked.

have added the original code

the collection class

```
public class VariableData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

String _Source;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The source.
    /// </value>
    public String Source
    {
        get { return _Source; }
        set
        {
            _Source = value; if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Source"));
        }
    }
}
```

**the binding**

```
<TextBox Name="textBoxFileLocation"
         Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource mapTypeToDataConverter}, ConverterParameter=41}"
         Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
</TextBox>
```

**the converter**

```
public class MapTypeToDataConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the source data before passing it to the target for display in the UI.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The source data being passed to the target.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The <see cref="T:System.Type"/> of data expected by the target dependency property.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">An optional parameter to be used in the converter logic.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture of the conversion.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The value to be passed to the target dependency property.
    /// </returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "";

        VariableData cus = null;
        try
        {
            cus = (VariableData)value;
        }
        catch (Exception e3)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (cus == null)
            return "";

        int temp = int.Parse(parameter.ToString());

        int mapType = temp / 10;
        int whatToreturn = temp % 10;

        if (mapType != cus.MappingType)
        {
            if (whatToreturn == 3)
                return false;
            else
                return "";
        }

        switch (whatToreturn)
        {
            case 1:
                return cus.Source;
                break;
            case 2:
                return cus.Query;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (cus.Source != null && cus.Source.Length > 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
        }

        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value;
    }

    #endregion IValueConverter Members
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be binding the whole `VariableData` as the value then using a converter to extract the output you need.  Since the `VariableData` instance itself isn't changing (your `ConvertBack` is not returning a new object of type `VariableData`) there is no reason for the UI to believe that it needs to update its UI.

What you should do is drop the converter and bind to properties of `VariableData` move the logic you need into `VariableData` create additional properties as necessary.  If changing one property affects also another you can ensure that `PropertyChanged` events are raised for both.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `Mode=TwoWay` in the XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
```

*(not at an IDE at the moment so there might be typos)*

This will mean that the UI updates when `MyProperty` changes as well as `MyProperty` updating when the UI changes.

Comment: no .. still not two waybinding ... say ter are 10 objects in my datacontext colelction ... and i edit row 1 object property and click submit .. the the click handler goes and updates row 1 object properties and also row 5 and row 10 object properties ... i want the gui to reflect the changes made to row 5 and 10 ... and please note that all text properties are bound to converter ....

Comment: @pskk - can you edit your xaml into your question (the bit that displays your collection). I can't envisage the problem.